Defining two thresholds in a binary classification model
In the context of binary classification, models usually output probability values ranging from $0$ to $1$, and then use a default threshold of $0.5$ to decide wether to classify an observation in one class or the other. In this sense, the interval $[0,0.5)$ could be interpreted as "low risk" of the outcome happening, and the interval $[0.5, 1]$ would be the "high risk" range of probabilities.
I am aware that one can also use the ROC curve to find a more "optimal" threshold, by choosing the threshold that corresponds to the elbow of the graph.
In my context, I am interested in defining two thresholds, in order to have three intervals that could be interpreted as low, medium and high risk intervals. Now I know it sounds strange but bare with me. In my context I have found that often the TN and TP test predictions (classified with the default $0.5$ threshold) have probabilities very close to $0$ and $1$ respectively, meaning the model is very confident in its prediction; whereas the FP and FN predictions tend to lie closer to a middle strip around 0.5, meaning the model makes a prediction without as much certainty. So what one would like is for those uncertain predictions to be interpreted as having nor low or high but medium risk of the target variable being positive. This middle interval should be wide enough and well placed enough as to encompass as many of the FP and FN test predictions, while encompassing as few as possible of the TP and TN ones.
I'm aware of this question, and it is not what I'm asking here.
My initial idea was to use the default threshold or the ROC curve optimal threshold, as the center of the "medium risk" interval, using a radius of $0.15$ in order to have an interval of length $0.3$ which is roughly a third of the whole interval, which only makes sense if the threshold is close to $0.5$. Alternatively, I also thought of defining a function of the two ends of the middle interval, that rewards for the FP and FN predictions it reaches but punishes for each TP and TN prediction that lands inside of it, and then optimize that function to find an optimal middle interval. However these approaches feel very loose and I would like a more rigorous solution for this problem, hopefully making use of the ROC curve, as to sort of "generalize" the elbow rule to find two thresholds instead of just one. I would prefer the answer to be a method that already exists in the literature and has already been discussed somewhere, as me myself haven't been able to find any references online regarding this question. If there is no reference, I would also appreciate any feedback on my initial ideas or a better suggestion.
I will add the confusion matrix of my model to illustrate the previously mentioned situation. In each cell of the matrix I added a box plot to show the distribution of the probabilities output by the model in that specific cell, along with a red vertical line representing the default $0.5$ threshold. Notice how the TN and TP boxes are closer to $0$ and $1$ respectively, whereas the FP and FN ones are evidently closer to the middle. I won't show any code as my question is more theoretical than practical.


I would suggest you do not think in terms of TP etc. (what does this even mean if multiple thresholds are involved), but in terms of "probabilistic prediction + threshold -> decision/action", which can absolutely lead to different decisions based on multiple thresholds. Then assess your modeling-decision pipeline using explicit costs, which in turn need to be based on your actual decision context.

What is your question exactly?

Stephan, thank you for linking that answer as it is indeed related to my question. If I understood your conclussions there correctly, say my project is for medical classification: should I then show the output probabilities of the model to the medical professionals and suggest taylor made performance metrics that can meet their criteria as far as defining this "medium risk" interval? I understand I was constraining myself by thinking in termsnof TP, TN, etc, but would you suggest any other existing metrics for evaluating a model with a low, medium and high risk classes?

Calimo, my question is if someone knows an already existing way of rigorously defining a medium risk interval as described in my question, and if not, I ask for suggestions in the process of defining an appropriate evaluation metric I can optimise in order to find such interval.
